# How do you convert the two digit year integer to four digits in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

There are three columns in my [dataset][1] that I wanted to combine into one. I did so like this:

```
from datetime import date
data['DATE'] = data.apply(lambda x: date(int(x['Yr']), int(x['Mo']), int(x['Dy'])), axis=1)
```

And then I dropped those three columns 'Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy'.
The problem is that I'm getting something like this:

```
DATE
0061-01-01
0061-01-02
0061-01-03
0061-01-04
0061-01-05
```

, where I expected it to be something like this:

```
DATE
1961-01-01
1961-01-02
1961-01-03
1961-01-04
1961-01-05
```

So, before I created the column 'DATE' I had to convert the two digits 'Yr' column into four digits manually.

```
def yr_fx(df):
    for i in range(len(df['Yr'])):
        df['Yr'][i] = '19'+str(df['Yr'][i])`
```

I created the above function to do the job for me but the problem is that it's taking way too long to execute like 2 - 3 minutes. And it also shows this warning:

```
C:\Users\abc\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
```

I want to know the efficient way of doing this.

Comment: are your columns in the following format `Yr = 61` `Mo = 12` `Dy=15` ?

Comment: Yr, Mo and Dy are the column names, Yes.

Comment: please don't use images, provide a textual example of your dataframe. have a read of [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: @Datanovice I will definitely do so.

Comment: Have a go and editing this question and i'll redact my down vote for a up-vote, remember people need textual examples to test in their own enviroments. Best of luck bhai.

Comment: @Datanovice I edited my answer. And I appreciate you pointing that out since I'm fairly new when it comes to posting questions.

Comment: That's absoutely fine, make sure you green tick the appropriate solution, so this can be closed. Happy coding my man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204424/discussion-between-abhishek-panchal-and-datanovice).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Yr": 61, "Mo": 12, "Dy": 15}, index=[0])

df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(
    df["Yr"].astype(str) + "-" + df["Mo"].astype(str) + "-" + df["Dy"].astype(str)
)

df["Date"] = df["Date"] + pd.DateOffset(years=-100)

print(df)
```

---

#### Result:

```
   Yr  Mo  Dy       Date
0  61  12  15 1961-12-15
```

Comment: Before using "DateOffset", What if I want all the years to be in the 1900s because I have now the years between 61 and 78. So year 61-68 becomes 2061-2068 and others in the 1900s, but if I use pd.DateOffset(years=-100) to turn 2061-2068 to 1961-1968 then other years are now in the 1800s. How do I turn just the year 2061-2068 to 1961-1968 while keeping other years intact?

Comment: Yes that's quite simple, give me a little bit and I'll edit for you @Abhishek Panchal

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way - we can make use of the fact that [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) can interpret `year`, `month` and `day` properly if they are your column names. We'll also use [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to add 1900 years inline.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Yr": 61, "Mo": 12, "Dy": 15}, index=[0])

pd.to_datetime(df[['Yr', 'Mo', 'Dy']]
               .rename(columns={'Yr': 'year',
                                'Mo': 'month',
                                'Dy': 'day'})
               .assign(year=lambda x: x['year']+1900))
```

[out]

```
0   1961-12-15
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: this is much more flexible, and reduces the need for all the string concatenation @OP use this answer.

Comment: @Datanovice I actually prefer your solution here & it's how I would actually do it for real! Just added this as a fun little alternative

Answer (score 0):

According to the python datetime docs (https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

You should also be able to use lower case y to indicate that the year format is only two digits. Then you can reformat to four year date with dt.strftime and an upper case y. For my data it assumed year 2000 and above so you may have to write a lambda function if you have dates before 2000.

```
data['DATE_reformatted'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DATE'], format="%y-%m-%d").dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```